# DB2 SQL Group by statement

Tags: db2, cognos

I am using *IBM Cognos Framework Manager* to create a report and within this report we need to isolate the last row but that is not my question. I am trying to use GROUP BY clause to achieve it and it always throws back an error whatever I do.

Table is named THESIS_ADVISER with the following columns:

```
THESIS_ID
FACULTY_ID
START_SY
START_TERM
```

Why does my group by clause not work?

```
Select * 
From SAMPLE.THESIS_ADVISER THESIS_ADVISER
Group by 
    THESIS_ADVISER.THESIS_ID
```

> Error generated:
>   RQP-DEF-0177 An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-9'.
>   UDA-SQL-0107 A general exception has occurred during the operation "prepare".
>   [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0119N An expression starting with "THESIS_ID" specified in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified. SQLSTATE=42803

Comment: Your group by does not make any sense. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY clause is looking a set of columns to be grouped for doing some aggregate functions on one or more remaining columns. For example, if you want to select the latest transaction date for a given user in a given department, then you would do MAX(Transaction Date) ......GROUP BY Employee, Department

If I understand correctly, you are trying to keep the rows belonging to certain THESIS_ID together. If that is the case, use ORDER BY clause for THESIS_ID. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all: you must have in the SELECT list all the same columns that you have in the GROUP BY clause, plus may be some aggregate functions.